# Deleting all public groups from Org

Tags: apex, soql, metadata-api, dml, public-group

We have an utility which imports all data from one org to another, this results in creating public groups every time import operation is carried out. Is there any way we can perform delete operation on Public groups before starting new import.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can simply run SOQL query to select groups and perform `delete` in anonymous apex

```
delete [
    select Id
    from Group 
    where DeveloperName = 'test'
        and Type = 'Regular'
];
```

also you can use [ant migrating tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm) to delete public groups

in order to delete metadata you need to run [destructive changes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm)

in short, you will need to name in `destructiveChanges.xml` file, that you want to delete public groups

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Group</name>
    </types>
</Package>
```